# assistance with post build event command

Tags: batch-file, msbuild, command, nuget, post-build-event

I am using the following as a post build event:

```
FOR %%a in ($(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)MyLibrary.*.dll) DO CALL :package %%~na

:package 
"$(SolutionDir)\..\..\..\Packages\NuGet.exe" pack "$(SolutionDir)%1\%1.csproj" -o "$(SolutionDir)\..\..\..\Packages"
```

The function of the above is to find all MyLibrary dll's in a folder and create a nuget package from them. There are 5 files that match the search for MyLibrary.*.dll. However only 1 package gets created - the first file found.

Anyone see any issue with the above as to why its only creating one package and not 5. Is there a syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `goto :eof` call after the NuGet line; which signifies the end of the `:package` function.  Therefore, the loop is calling the function, but the function is never returning to the loop.

```
FOR %%a in ($(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)MyLibrary.*.dll) DO CALL :package %%~na
goto End

:package 
"$(SolutionDir)\..\..\..\Packages\NuGet.exe" pack "$(SolutionDir)%1\%1.csproj" -o "$(SolutionDir)\..\..\..\Packages"
goto :eof

:End
```

Comment: I think there should also be a `goto :eof` after the `for` statement, otherwise the `:package` code runs again after the loop, but with different arguments…

Comment: @mousio correct, there should also be a goto to pass over the function so that it is not run again or a goto :eof to end the script at that point.